# How to add multiple employees to a Product

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I am very NEW to SQL and know few things here and there.

I am puzzled with this for a couple of days and can't find an answer for it. What I am trying to do is to assign multiple people to a project in way that their name would appear based on their Job Assignments.

For example:
I have table called `Products` and in that table I have:

```
Model_ID -> This is set to Primary Key 
Model_Name,
PM,
Designer
```

I have another table called `Employee` and in that table I have:

```
Employee_ID -> This is set to Primary Key 
First_Name,
Last_Name,
email,
Job_Title
```

Under Job_Title, for each Employee, I would have their position in the company like PM, Designer, AE, Server PM, etc.

What I am trying to do is to list a corresponding Employee name under a `Products` table `PM` column if person is assigned as a PM and under `Designer` column if person is assigned as a Designer for that product. I have included screenshot of my diagram...

I understand I don't have them linked because everything I tried so far, I couldn't make it work. I am just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Any help/ pointers would be greatly appreciated and I am open to create new tables if needed (like separate job functions out of Employee table into a separate table, etc.)

The end result should look like:

[image]

Comment: I have a solution here for you, both as SQL code and how you would do it in Design View.  If it's what you are looking for, don't forget to 'accept' this as the answer.

Comment: That did the trick... Thank you very much for your help. It's much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the following should do the trick:

```
Select p.Product_ID, p.Model_Name, e1.First_Name as PM, e2.First_Name as Designer
    from Product p
    left join Employee e1 on e1.Employee_ID = p.PM
    left join Employee e2 on e2.Employee_ID = p.Designer
```

If you want to use full names, then:

```
Select p.Product_ID, p.Model_Name, e1.First_Name + ' ' + e1.Last_Name as PM, e2.First_Name + ' ' + e2.Last_Name as Dessigner
    from ...
```

I used Left Joins in case not every product has both a PM and Designer assigned yet.  You should probably have two foreign key relationships on your project table though, one for PM and one for Designer, and both will use the Employee table's Employee_ID as the key.

#### Design View

If you want to do this in Design View, I think you will need to add a second copy of the Employee table and 'link' the PM field to Employee_ID in one Employee table and the Designer field to Employee_ID in the other.

I hope this helps.